# How do I add a command permission to specific user to do it without password?

Tags: permissions, password, sudo

I want to give permission to a user to do shutdown command without password. Shutdown command need root privileges. If I give `NOPASSWD` in `/etc/sudoers`, the user can do all command that need root privileges without entering password. I want the user just has `shutdown` command permission without password, not other commands.

My exact goal is to do shutdown automatically after finished downloading a huge file. So, the user can do this:

```
wget *download link* || shutdown -hP now
```

I read somewhere that sudo can only remember password for about 15 minutes. So, if I do

```
sudo wget *download link* || shutdown -hP now
```

or

```
wget *download link* || sudo shutdown -hP now
```

and downloading process take more than 15 minutes, it will asking for password when I'm not around.

So, How do I add a command permission to specific user to do it without password?

Answer (score 1):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers:

Try adding the following to `/etc/sudoers` with `<username>` filled in appropriately:

```
Cmnd_Alias SHUTDOWN_CMDS = /sbin/poweroff, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown
<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SHUTDOWN_CMDS
```